# Regex For AlphaNumeric with special chars

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and trying to find a regex, which will allow Alphanumeric or text but not complete numeric with special characters like "," , "'","()" ,"/" ,".".

```
ex: aa12,--allowed
aa,-allowed
123-Not allowed
123,--not allowed
123,a--allowed.
```

Alpha Numeric-

```
\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\s]*$
```

is working but stuck with including special characters. Any help?

Comment: How about `^\S*[a-zA-Z]\S*$`

Comment: Put all special chars in the square brackets: `[,'\(\)/"\.]` notice that I escaped with a backslash all chars that have special meaning to the regex  itself like `.`

Comment: Where is the *numeric* part and *special characters* in it? @anubhava

Comment: Hence the title you mean? @anubhava

Comment: Then simply `\S*[a-z]+\S*` with the `i` flag for case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to make sure the string contains a character, just match with

```
.*[a-zA-Z].*
```

if you need to **match** the full line. Or even simpler

`[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-z]`

The last if you can set the *case insensitive* flag (you haven't stated regex flavor). These last two will simply match if there's a letter in the text. And I can't see that what you're looking for is anything but that.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ktrtns/3).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in all scenarios..

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[_@.#&+-])[A-Za-z0-9_@.#&+-]{8,}$/
```

Here is how it works,

- `^(?=.*\d)` - checks for at-least one digit in string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - checks for at-least one lowercase in string
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - checks for at-least one uppercase in string
- `(?=.*[_@.#&+-])` - checks for at-least one special character in string
- `{8,}` - checks the string length for a minimum of 8 characters

---

Click here to test it out at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Probably I couldn't convey the issue am trying to sort it out. My case is

If All Numbers--Error
If All Special Characters--Error
If only Numbers + special Characters--Error

Remaining all should be flaged as non error. For the special characters, I get a specific list to let them in. I tried & tried finally Below Regex seems working. Any Optimizations?
\d*([a-zA-Z,/().]*[a-zA-Z][,/().]*)[a-zA-Z\d\s]*$

Comment: Is this meant as an answer? Because it isn't working at all. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/ktrtns/5). It **requires** a *special* or alpha character, followed by an alpha character, in turn followed by a **mandatory** *special character*, which doesn't match your requirements. And - how doesn't the first one I suggested work? It meets your stated requirements. Maybe you should post this as a comment to your question instead?

Comment: \d*([a-zA-Z,\/().]*[a-zA-Z][,\/().]*)[a-zA-Z\d\s]*$

Yeah..That was supposed to be in comment.                                         
 Trying To understand Your explanation
 is that regex means
 Zero or more digits then zero or more alpha/special then alpha then zero or more special?

Comment: "Trying To understand Your explanation"? The link is to **your** regex (the one last in this **answer**), that doesn't work at all. Mine is in **my** answer.